# Convert string to numeric (11,6) using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis-2012

I have the data coming from a flat file source. "unit_Price" (column name) it has the following data.

**Unit_Price**
00465797857

precisely, I have to convert this values to 465.797857.

In the SSIS package, I conevrted it to DT_R8 and multiplied with 0.000001 so, I got the value in staging table 465.797857. (Staging table I set the datatype for this column as float)

(Datatype in original table is numeric(11,6)) while moving the data from staging to original table, It is rounding off the value to 465.798000. I tried set the datatype as float and real but it is rounding off the value in any case.

Is there anyway, I can get the value in the Original table as it is in Staging table. ? (i.e 465.797857)

Thanks

Comment: Why did you decide to use `float` in your staging table? Just use the same data type as the original table `numeric(11,6)`

Comment: Thanks Nick. I don't know, I tried numeric(11,6) before on the staging, it gave me an error. But I tried now and it worked fine. I must have done something wrong.